# resize and calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that when you click on the html it checks the width of a number of elements and compares it with the windows width. I can't get it to work with the resize function. I think I'm calling it wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var conditionWidth = checkWidth()
  });

  function checkWidth() {
    var elementWidth = 1;
    $("div>div").each(function() {
      if ($(this).width() > $("html").width() / 2) {
        elementWidth = 2;
      }
    });
    return elementWidth;
  }

  var conditionWidth = checkWidth()

  $("body").off("click").click(function() {
    alert(conditionWidth);
  });
})
```

```css
div div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.rectangle1 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
}
.rectangle2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
}
.rectangle3 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="rectangle1"></div>
  <div class="rectangle2"></div>
  <div class="rectangle3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `var` to declare the variable in the resize handler the the variable is local to the resize handler method and the value of the closure scope(dom ready handler) is not updated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var conditionWidth = checkWidth()

    $(window).resize(function () {
        //when you use var it becomes a local variable
        conditionWidth = checkWidth()
    });

    function checkWidth() {
        var elementWidth = 1;
        $("div>div").each(function () {
            if ($(this).width() > $("html").width() / 2) {
                elementWidth = 2;
            }
        });
        return elementWidth;
    }

    $("body").off("click").click(function () {
        alert(conditionWidth);
    });
})
```